# How to send authorization header (or) access token in avro-console-producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

We have a SSL enabled kafka broker and Schema Registry access is through Keycloak. From external machine, I am able to send the data using kafka-console-producer and below is my configs.

ssl.properties:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.truststore.location=truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

jaas.conf:

```
KafkaClient
{
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="<user-name>"
password="<password>";
};
```

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf"
 
./kafka-console-producer --bootstrap-server broker-url:<external_port> --topic sample.data --producer.config ssl.properties
```

> Hi  sample data sent

**I am able to see them using consumer**

Now, for schema registry I need to get the token as shown below:

```
curl  -k --data 'grant_type=password&client_id=schema-registry-client&username=username&password=password' https://<keycloakurl>/auth/realms/<namespace>/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

output:

```
{"access_token":"<access_token>","expires_in":600,"refresh_expires_in":1800,"refresh_token":"<refresh_token>","token_type":"bearer","not-before-policy":0,"session_state":"4117e69c-afe9-43ae-9756-90b151f0b536","scope":"profile email"}

 curl -k  -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>"  
 https://<sc_url>/schemaregistry/subjects
```

output:

```
 ["test.data-value"]
```

Question is, how can I use the access_token in avro-console-producer ? I dont see a way.

Answer (score 0):

Based [on the source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/6.0.1-post/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/rest/RestService.java#L935) for the Registry REST client, something like these properties should be what you want (untested)

```
bearer.auth.credentials.source="STATIC_TOKEN"
bearer.auth.token="your token"
```

Comment: No, this did not work. I can share the snapshot in sometime.

Comment: To clarify, the first property is a literal, only the second value here needs changed. Other than that, it's not clear what version of the Avro producer you're trying to use, so these settings may not match the source code I linked to

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I am using confluent-6.0.1 avro-producer.

Comment: I am able to get the versions of registered topics using access token. However below command is failing: 
./kafka-avro-console-producer --bootstrap-server <boot_strap> --topic <topc>  --producer.config ssl.properties --property value.schema.id=1 --property schema.registry.url="https://<url>/schemaregistry/" --property bearer.auth.credentials.source="STATIC_TOKEN" --property bearer.auth.token="Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" and getting error as below:

Comment: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving schema for id 1
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: If you look at the source code I linked to, `"Authorization: Bearer "` is already added into the request, so you should only set the token. You might also want to put those properties into the `ssl.properties` file